# How do I change the css of a link when visited, unvisited or hovered using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink

So in my html code I have a line of code that looks like what is shown in the bottom:

```
    <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">Find out more</a>
```

and I want to use java script to change the color of this link when visited, not visited or hovered.
In other word, what I am looking for is a way to do what is shown below but with java script.

```
    a.visited {css property}; a.link {css property}; a.hover {css property}
```

Does anyone know how? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use CSS for this? It's what it's built for.

Comment: CSS pseudo-classes do not suit you - `:hover, :visited, :link` [etc.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes#location_pseudo-classes)?

Comment: It's better that use pseudo-classes to do it!

Comment: I know its better if I just want to directly change the style at the start, but I want it to change on the click of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your CSS, you can have a default style of your link as below and make use of the CSS variables

```
a{
    --color:lightblue;
    --hoverColor: red;
    --visitedColor: blue; 
    color: var(--color);
}

a:hover {color:var(--hoverColor);}
a:visited:hover {color:var(--hoverColor);}
a:visited {color:var(--visitedColor);}
```

From your JavaScript, you can override the hoverColor and visitedColor css variable as below

```
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function(link){
    link.style.setProperty('--hoverColor','orange');
});

document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function(link){
    link.style.setProperty('--visitedColor','blue');
});
```

Comment: From what I understand, the OP doesn't want to fix the style of the link in the css, but change the color of the link during a click event.
It is not possible for javascript to detect if a link is visited in either Firefox or Chrome, so I believe my suggestion will help.

Comment: Wow, this worked! However there is something you missed, at first it did nothing so I changed it up a bit and realized that you need 

        for(i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
           a[i].style.setProperty('--hoverColor', color);
        };

Perhaps you could add it to your answer so that other people could see?

Comment: also for some reason that although visited color and unvisited color works, hover color doesn't work, any clues to why it is happening?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have updated my answer.

The reason why the hover color doesn't work could be due to the sequence of the css style. I put the a:visited after a:hover, hence if your link is visited and you hover over the link, it will take the style of a:visited instead of a:hover.
To resolve that you can either reserve the order for the a:visited and a:hover or add another a:visited:hover style to take care of this condition.